# WebPack 4 error 'document is not defined'

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to switch from parcel to Webpack (4.42.1), but when I'm doing `npm start` or `npm run build` I'm gettin the error

"ReferenceError: document is not defined"

I've cut a demo app from my project with exact same webpack.config.js
The demo app is located here: https://github.com/vbogretsov/webpack-please-help

P.S. The trick with globalObject: 'this' did not helped.

The initial error was localStorage is not defined, when I tried to use window.localStorage the error was 'window is not defined', it seems like issue related to wrong target environment but it is target: 'web' by default according to documentation.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by incorrect index.html: the body was

```html
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

but should be

```html
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Like described in docs for [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)